# SecureFile Understanding Compression Type

Tags: oracle

It is known that there are 3 types of compression: HIGH, MEDIUM which is the default and LOW, I have researched on the internet and have found that what differentiates them is the amount of CPU each one requires and the resulting size of the compressed file, apart from Is there any other criteria for use? For example having to do with the size of the original file

Comment: I am not aware of any such criteria. It takes more work to get a higher compression ratio and conserve more storage capacity, so your choice of compression level should be about balancing 1) how much CPU you have available 2) how much storage capacity you have 3) how frequently the data needs to be accessed or modified. Original file size might be relevant if the data is accessed (and therefore uncompressed) frequently, but frequent access would point you towards low compression or no compression regardless of how big the file is.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very, very good question. Here is the practical answer:

The compression ratio depends heavily on the data and is nearly impossible to predict. If the table is not too large, I simply create 4 copies of it and compare the resulting sizes:

```
CREATE TABLE t0 (c CLOB) LOB (c) STORE AS SECUREFILE sf0 (NOCOMPRESS);
CREATE TABLE tl (c CLOB) LOB (c) STORE AS SECUREFILE sfl (COMPRESS LOW);
CREATE TABLE tm (c CLOB) LOB (c) STORE AS SECUREFILE sfm (COMPRESS MEDIUM);
CREATE TABLE th (c CLOB) LOB (c) STORE AS SECUREFILE sfh (COMPRESS HIGH);

INSERT INTO t0 SELECT c FROM s0;
INSERT INTO tl SELECT c FROM t0;
INSERT INTO tm SELECT c FROM t0;
INSERT INTO th SELECT c FROM t0;
```

Now you can measure the sizes of the table itself, the LOB and the LOB index:

```
SELECT b.compression, b.table_name,
       (SELECT sum(bytes) FROM user_segments s 
         WHERE s.segment_name = b.table_name)   as tab_bytes,
       (SELECT sum(bytes) FROM user_segments s 
         WHERE s.segment_name = b.segment_name) as lob_bytes,
       (SELECT sum(bytes) FROM user_segments s 
         WHERE s.segment_name = b.index_name)   as ind_bytes,
       (SELECT sum(bytes) FROM user_segments s 
         WHERE s.segment_name IN (b.table_name, 
                 b.segment_name, b.index_name)) as sum_bytes
  FROM user_lobs b 
 WHERE table_name like 'T%'
 ORDER BY DECODE(b.compression, 'NO',0,'LOW',1,'MEDIUM',2 ,'HIGH',3);
```

If you use `DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW`, you get sizes like that:

```
COMPRESSION TABLE_NAME TAB_BYTES LOB_BYTES IND_BYTES SUM_BYTES
NO          T0             65536  25362432     65536  25493504
LOW         TL             65536  16973824     65536  17104896
MEDIUM      TM             65536   8585216     65536   8716288
HIGH        TH             65536   8585216     65536   8716288
```

In this case, I would go for `MEDIUM` compression, as 8585216 bytes are already good enough and not improved by `HIGH` compressen.

If you use `ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW`, LOBs are stored in the table segment instead of the LOB segment if there are smaller than [3965](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_tables.htm#i1006363) bytes. Therefore the table segment is usally bigger than with `DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW`:

```
COMPRESSION TABLE_NAME TAB_BYTES LOB_BYTES IND_BYTES SUM_BYTES
NO          T0            983040  16973824     65536  18022400
LOW         TL           2097152   5439488     65536   7602176
MEDIUM      TM            983040   4390912     65536   5439488
HIGH        TH           1048576   3342336     65536   4456448
```

Because some LOBs might compress so well that they become smaller than 3964 bytes, the table segment may actually become larger with compression.

For this example, I'd go with `ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW` and `COMPRESS HIGH`.

Comment: So you mean the best compression is high?

Comment: It really depends on the data. In my example `MEDIUM` compresses to 21.3% of the original size, and `HIGH` to 17.4%, so I would definitely use `HIGH` in this case.